# Remove completly a dataset from session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have to store a dataset into a session, because I have non persistent data for specific users to create reports.
In my Global.asax.cs I am storing a specific key into the cache. This cache is for the report and the report data (session-data-set).
After a specific time the report data is removed from cache and in the same method I am removing the dataset from the session, with Session.Remove().

Now I have the problem that I am not sure if this frees the memory, because if I store the DataSet into the Session I am storeing the reference.
But how can I completely free the space used by the DataSet?
If I think that at one time there are 20 users using this method, there is a lot of memory consumption...

Answer (score 1):

DataSet contains no unmanaged code, so there is no need to call Dispose() unless you are doing something funky.

You are removing the entry from the session dictionary as opposed to setting the value to null, which has a completely different result.

Although I am not able to specifically confirm due to lack of information, I do believe you are doing what you can and there is nothing more you can do.

Have you actually managed to confirm this is an issue, or are you being pragmatic?

Comment: The question is more like 'am I doing it in the best way?', or is there something I am missing? Maybe it is also going out of my comprehension. I only want to completely remove the used data , so is there any data after my remove, if yes is it removed by the garbage collector in future or can I remove it manually?

Comment: I can see no other way of doing this, the GC will deal with the dataset allocation as and when, there is no more you can do. Based on this, I would say yes, you are doing it the best way.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Session variables are the path to the dark side. Session leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.